# macos 10.14.4: unable to update xcode

Tags: mac, download, xcode, software-update

I upgraded my macbook pro to 10.14 Mojave, then went to app store, where I attempted to upgrade to the latest xcode. A partial circle began spinning, but then it said I have to upgrade macos further to 10.14.4 before I can use the latest xcode. So I left app store and updated macos to 10.14.4. This entailed a reboot. Now, back at app store, Xcode shows a partial circle with a square in the middle. How do I resume the download? I find no button or link to do this. Going to the Developer Tools website and attempting to download Xcode from there, only sends me back to the App Store. I also tried command-line

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

and it tells me

> error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

How can I install the latest xcode on this macbook pro?

Next, I removed every file and directory that contains the string "xcode", even in my .Trash, and rebooted again. But when I try the

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

it gives the same error,

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Software Update tells me "Your Mac is up to date --- macOS Mojave 10.14.4."

App Store has changed now; it has an "update" button next to Xcode, not a partial circle with a square in the middle, and when I doubleclick that button, a new page opens up devoted to Xcode, with another "update" button. But when I click that button, although it flashes or appears to perform a  backflip, no download takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial circle, or arc, with a square at its center, proved to be a progress bar twisted around onto itself, like a dog reaching for its own tail. As long as the arc was open, i.e., as long as the circle was incomplete, the download was incomplete.  Clicking this arc turned it into a picture of a cloud with an arrow pointing down from it.  Clicking the cloud turned it back into an arc with a square at the center.

The arc really was growing, only at imperceptible speed --- like the hour hand on an analog clock.  Also, every time the computer went to sleep, the download stopped or paused. But after more than a day, the arc abruptly turned into an "OPEN" button. Clicking OPEN, launched Xcode on my computer.